# Possible chances of getting org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query"

Tags: hibernate

I am using hibernate 3.6 in my project since last 6 months, but some time i am getting "org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query" error. i don't know the exact reason.
i am getting confused from different answers from diff sites  :-( !!
What might be possible scenario in which this error occurs?

Comment: This is article contain some basic error and exception but not the one which i am looking for...[link](http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/java/hibernate-common-errors-and-exceptions.texy)